# Why does using touch, to create an empty file with no filetype, create various kinds of files?

Tags: touch, finder

On macOS I am running a shell script that uses `touch` to create an empty file without an extension. The files created using the same script randomly have different Kinds, i.e. "Document", "Unix executable", "TextEdit.app Document" with no apparent differences between them. No extended attributes

```
/usr/bin/touch /Volumes/SDrive/complete/.hashes/"${1}"___"${9}"
```

variables contain text...

example filename:
"NOVA.S48E14.Particles.Unknown.720p.WEB.h264___221a636b1f174def7a72d90a9c9d4e9af6aab6ee"

I am curious why an empty file with no extension would be interpreted to be anything other than Kind "Document" when created with the `touch` command, and if there is a method to specify without using an extension?

I have not been able to test this on any other OS.

Comment: I can see how a guesstimator would classify your example filename as "no recognized extension, but it _does_ have `.h264` in the name, so I'll guess it's a video". Does something like that hold for your other filenames? (No idea how you would get "Unix executable" with that, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a documented answer.

The file `kind` [is said to be a "tag"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422232/how-to-find-out-what-i-am-able-to-look-for-in-spotlight), and seems to be a *metadata* element related to the [`kMDItemKind` field](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html). Its primary purpose seems to be for classifying search results from `Spotlight`.

But perhaps the most relevant answer to your question is that there is no "why": The file `kind` tag is not created by `touch`, but by some other process that Apple has chosen not to disclose. Your results (which are repeatable) are *prima facie* evidence that - at least in the case of files created by `touch` - the `kind` tag is an arbitrary artifact of Apple's process with no relationship to the file created.